# VB Error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to check if a row contains nothing or NIL but the code returns this error.

> Input string was not in a correct format

What am I doing wrong?

```
If drExcel("NSN") IsNot "" Or "NIL" Then
```

Comment: try `If drExcel("NSN") IsNot Nothing`.  You are matching a string with `null` types. Or `If Convert.toString( drExcel("NSN")) IsNot ""` to handle null values.

Comment: also vb.net does not work like that: `If drExcel("NSN") IsNot "" OrElse  drExcel("NSN") IsNot "NIL" Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not direct check or condition. You can do like this

```
If drExcel("NSN") IsNot "" Or drExcel("NSN") IsNot "NIL" Then
```